# error: getrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE): Operation not permitted. Proftpd on Embbeded Linux enviorment

Tags: linux, embedded, proftpd

I've been trying to use proftpd on Arm7 Embedded linux.

After starting the execution, it delivers this message:

```
error: getrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE): Operation not permitted
```

The Proftpf version is 1.3.4b. Any clue about whatever could cause getrlimit fail?

Thank you very much.

Comment: privileges? does it work with `root` user?

Comment: It doesnt worked for root user. I've checked also the RLIMIT_CORE, and was set to 'unlimited' by a collegue

Comment: EPERM is weird for `getrlimit`. You [aren't the only one to have observed this](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2011-April/042860.html): it seems that some libc return this error to say “not implemented”. What libc are you using?

Comment: This should hopefully be fixed in the next proftpd release; see [this commit](https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/commit/e9920eb5639835222783ebabc7cceaadf408f959).

Answer (score 1):

In my case the EPERM error was caused by Large Files support enabled in build configuration. It caused [_FILE_OFFSET_BITS](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#index-_005fFILE_005fOFFSET_005fBITS) to be defined as `64` and therefore `getrlimit()` call became actually a `getrlimit64()` call, which failed (see below). Disabling Large File support fixed the issue. I'm working on an embedded ARM application, so hopefully disabling Large File support won't hurt me much.

**Update half a year later:**

As it turned out, I needed Large File support even on the embedded system, to be able to use mmap() with addresses > 2GB (to access hardware registers). To allow this, but still avoid calling getrlimit64 instead of getrlimit, I defined _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 project wide, and in the single unit where I called getrlimit, I redefined _FILE_OFFSET_BITS before including `<sys/resource.h>`:

```
#if _FILE_OFFSET_BITS == 64
# undef _FILE_OFFSET_BITS
# define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 32
#endif
#include <sys/resource.h> 
//...
//call getrlimit()
```

**But why getrlimit64() failed with EPERM:**

As per Gilles comment to the original question above, this is probably a way my libc returns "not implemented" error. See this [thread](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2011-April/042860.html) for another example of the same EPERM usage.